# How does Venmo's emoji auto-complete feature work, technically?

Tags: python, python-3.x, emoji, venmo

Venmo rolled out their emoji auto-complete feature pretty much a week after coming up with it over a [pizza dinner](https://medium.com/non-disclosure/recreating-the-of-emoji-autocomplete-4fc2456a02a0).

How would one implement this with Python? Are there any libraries or packages that would make this an easy implementation?

Comment: Which part do you find problematic? Matching a word to an emoji, creating an emoji, doing any kind of auto-complete, plugging the solution into some existing product, or something else?

Comment: The first and third - matching a word to an emoji and doing it with auto-complete pretty instantaneously, like Venmo does it

Comment: Well that is one question too many. You have to tackle one thing at a time. Implement what you know, try to implement what you don't know. Anyway, for matching words to emojis, I'd create a big dictionary of all words which have emojis related. To build that dictionary, I'd search the internet and gather useful data.

Comment: Gotchu, that first part definitely makes sense, thank you. My remaining questions are around doing any kind of live auto-complete in Python, although maybe that's outside the scope of this current question

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the exact author implementation in the Medium article you mentioned, but a naive implementation would look like this:

- tag each of the emoji with what they can represent.
- create a map from these word to the corresponding emoji
- during auto-complete search the recommended words in your map and recommend that emoji instead of the word.